# Is http://www.dyndnscommunity.com/ part of the SO community?

Tags: discussion, sister-site

Their site looks like a copy of SO, but when I signed up for an account, there's no way to associate my SO ID with their site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a SE 2.0 site by definition, because it doesn't have the SE 2.0 branding in the upper left hand corner.

I think it's a Stack Exchange 1.0 site. View source and look at the meta-tags.

Comment: SE 0.9, to be exact.